# Программа скомпилированная на x64, не работает на x32 разрядной системе

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Добрый день.

Написал на Python 3.5.2 программу которая собирает информацию о компьютере и заливает её в БД. Сбор информации идет через модуль `wmi`. Затем я через `pyinstaller` делаю .exe.

На х64 битных системах всё работает. А вот на х32 - нет.

Для эксперимента взял Windows 7 x32, запустил скрипт, он отработал и закрылся как положено, никаких ошибок не выдал, но и в БД данные не добавил. Почему так происходит я не понимаю.

Модули которые я использую `wmi`, `requests`, `re`, `pymysql`, `datetime`

Comment: Лучше напишите что именно за "информацию о компьютере". WMI может опираться на драйвера, а на разных машинах они разные.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Модель компьютера, название процессора, название видеокарты, размер диска, версия windows